# How to debug a python websocket script that uses `.run_forever()` method (infinite event loop)

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, infinite-loop, vscode-debugger

I'm coding a script that connects to the Binance websocket and uses the `.run_forever()` method to constantly get live data from the site. I want to be able to debug my code and watch the values of variables as the change but I'm not sure how to do this as the script basically hangs on the line with the `.run_forever()` method, because it is an infinite event loop. This is by design as I want to continuously get live data (it receives a message approximately every second), but I can't think of a way a good way to debug it.

I'm using VSCode and here are some snippets of my code to help understand my issue. The message function for the websocket is just a bunch of technical analysis and trade logic, but it is also the function that contains all the changing variables that I want to watch.

```
socket = f"wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{Symbol}@kline_{interval}"

def on_open(ws):
    print("open connection")

def on_message(ws, message):
    global trade_list
    global in_position
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    
    candle = json_message['k'] # Accesses candle data

...[trade logic code here]...

def on_close(ws):
    print("Websocket connection close")


# ------------------------- Define a websocket object ------------------------ #
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)

ws.run_forever()
```

If more code is required to answer the question, then I can edit this question to include it (I'm thinking if you would like to have an idea of what variables I want to look at, I just thought it would be easier and simpler to show these parts).

Also, I know using `global` isn't great, once I've finished (or am close to finishing) the script, I want to go and tidy it up, I'll deal with it then.

Comment: I'll leave someone else to answer as I don't have much experience with this, but I believe you just need to `print()` inside your `on_open`, `on_message` and `on_close` functions, like in the examples: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client

Comment: Is printing really the only way? That's what I was hoping I could avoid as I've been doing that while I've developed the the script, but its fairly large now. If it really is the only way then, that's how I'll have to do it.

Comment: It's definitely not the only way, but what are you trying to achieve that it doesn't offer? I thought you were just trying to see variable values. If you want to step through the program, I think you'd be better off printing or saving to file the input, and debugging it step by step just by calling `on_message` without a websocket at all.

Comment: did you find a solution? and also, what do you mean with using global isn't great? because i am running a websocket script as well with global variables (which i thought were necessary).

Comment: @intStdu Unfortunately I just continued to print variables to see their values as the program ran. 
Global variables are typically seen as bad practice (unless they really have to be global). It's best to limit the scope of variables to the minimum scope you require. EG, its better to return a value from a function call and assign it to a variable, rather than create a global variable within the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party but the statement

```
websocket.enableTrace(True)
```

worked for me. Place it just before you define your websocket object and it will print all traffic in and out of the websocket including any exceptions that you might get as you process the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You mention debugging your code as the first item, so note that WebSocketApp even swallows Python runtime errors in its callback functions by default. This means that typos can make the code silently dysfunctional which is a real headache if you're unaware of the error suppression.

Initially, when developing your code, you probably want runtime errors sent to your terminal's standard error stream, so since websockets uses the logging module to handle errors, the following would achieve that:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG )
```